# jQuery appended text is invisible

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm trying to create a couple of buttons above a textarea to insert some HTML code -- a VERY poor-man's HTML editor. I have a couple of INPUT elements, and I'm using jQuery to set a click handler that will call's jQuery's `append()` or `html()` or `text()` functions.

The handler fires, it shows a debug alert(), but the text I'm trying to append doesn't show up in the textarea. When I inspect the textarea in Firebug, I see the text I'm appending as a child of the textarea -- but it's dimmed, as when an element's style is set to display:none. But Firebug's CSS inspector doesn't show any change to the display or visibility properties.

When I set the click handler to 'append()', and then click multiple times, in Firebug I see the text being added over and over again -- but each new chunk is still invisible. If I choose 'Edit HTML' in Firebug and then type some chars next to the appended text, the entire text block -- the text added by jQuery and the stuff I added in Firebug -- suddenly appear.

This also happens if I don't use a click handler, but call my append function using an inline handler like `onclick="javascript:insert('bold');"`

Anyone have any idea why the appended text is not displayed?

Here's the relevant code:

The HTML:

```
<input type='button' id='bold' value='B' onclick='javascript:insert("bold")' />

<textarea name='PersonalGreeting' id='PersonalGreeting'>default text</textarea>
```

The Javascript:

```
function insert( cmd )  {
    switch ( cmd )  {
        case 'bold':
            $('#PersonalGreeting').append('<b>bold text here</b>');
            break;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Clarification: the <b> tags don't need to display as bold in the textarea. The contents of the textarea will be injected into an email, whihc will render the <b> as bold. Sorry for the distraction -- tho inserting HTML is the point of these buttons, the problem is not that the text doesn't render in the textarea as bold, but that it doesn't display in the textarea at all. I'll try some of the suggestions in an hour or so and tell y'all what worked. Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would guess that jQuery is trying to append HTML DOM elements to the `textarea`.

Try using the [`val`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val) method to get and set the `textarea`'s value, like this:

```
$('#PersonalGreeting').val($('#PersonalGreeting').val() + '<b>bold text here</b>');
```

Comment: I can't believe there are so many similar questions here on StackOverfow that suggest the same solution, when (for me at least) it doesn't work! As the OP said, the text seems to be getting appended to the textarea, but it's invisible by any means other than typing "$('#textarea-id').val()" in the Chrome dev tools console. This is driving me crazy!! And all I'm appending is straight text...no HTML or anything else that should be hidden...WTF?!?!?!

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that you can't put HTML inside a `<textarea>`.  In fact, you can't append HTML elements to one at all.  You could use the `.val()` method to change the text shown inside, but that won't make it bold.  That will just make it have `<b>` showing as part of the text.

An off-the-shelf WYSIWYG editor like [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) is free and easy to implement.  Rather than reinvent the wheel (which is a **lot** harder than it might look), try an existing wheel out.

Comment: I think he wants to insert html source.

Comment: yes, that's correct -- I added a comment to my question to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: Heh, I'm doing this cuz I've not been able to get TinyMCE to work on this page. I'm maintaining some old legacy code and trying to shoehorn a new feature in; my first thought was TinyMCE, but while I can get it instantiated, something is preventing it from getting click and key events. So I thought I'd roll my own simple buttons.

Answer (score 1):

SLaks and VoteyDisciple are correct.  You're usage of append is faulty as you are perceiving it as a string function.

From http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append

> Append content to the inside of every
>   matched element. This operation is the
>   best way to insert elements inside, at
>   the end, of all matched elements. It
>   is similar to doing an appendChild to
>   all the specified elements, adding
>   them into the document.

Reinventing the wheel on this one is likely more headache than its worth unless this is an attempt to create a superior, competing product or for your own experimentation.

Also, I would shy away from use of obtrusive JavaScript as you have shown in your example with `onclick='javascript:insert("bold")'` embedded in the `input` element.  Instead, you'll have a more elegant solution with something like the following:

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="B" class="editor-command" >
<input type="button" value="I" class="editor-command" >
<input type="button" value="U" class="editor-command" >
```

**JavaScript** (not tested)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var textarea = $('#PersonalGreeting')
  $(".editor-command").each(function(i, node) {
    textarea.val(textarea.val() + '<$>text here</$>'.replace(/\$/g, node.value);
  });
});
```

Comment: Use the replace overload that takes a string (`.replace('$', node.value)`).  Or, just append the string.

Comment: Yes, I was doing it wrong -- append doesn't work as I thought it did. Re the obtrusive Javascript: yes, and my code originally used jQuery to set click handlers on the formattiog buttons. I removed that and replaced with inline click handlers while debugging to narrow down the problem. Now that I see val() is the appropriate method, I'll go back and replace the inline handlers.

Comment: @SLaks, the string overload will only replace the first match that it finds, not all of them (equivalent to not using the the 'g' flag).

Answer (score 0):

If the main issue is the textarea not being visible, I would try this:

```
$('#PersonalGreeting').append('<b>bold text here</b>').show();
```

Might be worth a shot.

edit: In the vain of not trying to reinvent the wheel, I've had success with [WYMEditor](http://www.wymeditor.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
 $('#PersonalGreeting').append('[b]bold text here[/b]');
```

But that won't actually render the text as bold. To be honest I'm not actually sure how to render text as bold inside a textarea, I imainge some js trickery.

Comment: It is not possible to apply formatting to a `textarea`, although you could put an element on top of it.